# Possible this Hashtable<Integer, String, String > hashtbl=new Hashtable<Integer, String, String>();

Tags: java, hashtable

i want this type of hashtable or vector or etc.,

```
Hashtable<Integer, String, String > hashtbl=new Hashtable<Integer, String, String>();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Be Specific in writing,better write the full code.So that at-least someone can answer your question.

Comment: i want store key, value1 ,value2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap of HashMaps like this:

```
 HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> mashmap= new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

When you want to add a value to Hashmap, you need to instantiate it too:

```
   HashMap<String, String> val = new HashMap<String, String>();
  // Do what you want to do with val
 mashmap.put(Key, val);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  create a object which accept two parameters like below :

```
public class MyObject {
  public MyObject(String val1, String val2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can use this object as the value of a Map :

```
Map<Integer, MyObject> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(1,new MyObject("value_1", "value_2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if we write this type of scenario we get the exception like:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Incorrect number of arguments for type Hashtable; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
    Incorrect number of arguments for type Hashtable; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Comment: He asked for methods of implementing a thing like he showed up. Not for stack trace..